# discount calculation in c# error on assigning value

Tags: c#, math

Can someone tell whats wrong with my code?

I've already tried casting first the value but I get the same result.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Discount function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ToDiscount">Price of an item</param>
    /// <param name="Discount">Discount</param>
    /// <param name="Type">Percent or Amount</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private decimal Discount(decimal ToDiscount, int Discount, DiscountType Type)
    {
        decimal temp = 0;
        try
        {
            if (Type == DiscountType.Percent)
            {
               int d = Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100) * ToDiscount);
                decimal f = ToDiscount - d;
                temp = f;
            }
            else if (Type == DiscountType.Currency)
            {
                decimal FinalDiscount = ToDiscount - Discount;

                temp = FinalDiscount;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Functions.ShowError(ex);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Example:

```
Discount(5000, 5, DiscountType.Percent);
//calculation: (5/100) * 5000 = 250
//discount: 5000 - 250 = 4750
```

but the with that function I've created I get result 5000. instead of 4750. 
I did break point on return temp; but when I hover this part `int d = Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100) * ToDiscount);`  no answer or no result.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it return an incorrect value?

Comment: how did you try cast exactly? this would work just fine if you cast Discount to double, or decimal

Comment: @selman22 

`int a = Discount / 100;
                    double b = Convert.ToDouble(a * ToDiscount);
                    double c = Convert.ToDouble(ToDiscount) - b;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
int d = Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100) * ToDiscount);
```

Does integer arithmetic, where `Discount / 100` will be zero for any discount between zero and 99.

You need to apply the discount via decimal, or floating point:

```
int d = Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100m) * ToDiscount);
```

As an aside, naming a variable `Type` is probably going to cause a few readability headaches down the line.

Comment: this one is right.. work on me. anyhow whats with this m on 100?

Comment: the `m` says it is a decimal literal instead of an integer literal.

Comment: the m is specifing the data type for the 100 id decimal, in this way the result will be processed as decimal without need other casting

Comment: The m suffix indicates a decimal literal value. The compiler internally constructs a Decimal struct from the value.

Answer (score 4):

`Discount / 100` is performing integer division, in which the result is 0.

Hence `(Discount / 100) * ToDiscount` also is 0, resulting in nothing being subtracted from `ToDiscount`.

I think that the best thing for you to do would be to change the type of `Discount` to being a `decimal`, which would solve all of your problems there.

Comment: this one is right also. but this `int d = Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100m) * ToDiscount);` is what im looking for.. thanks anyway... solved..

Comment: Not a problem. I'm curious, though: Is it your intention to only allow whole number discounts?

Comment: @IronMan84 good point, a 300% of discount will not be cool, the price will be negative

Answer (score 1):

When you make this: Convert.ToInt32((Discount / 100) * ToDiscount);
you will have have 0 because:

Discount /100 = 0 (if discount is intm the result will be int)

you should do a calculation with double numbers